# Emacs with CEDET changes copy/paste to include trailing spaces?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, cedet

I just started trying out CEDET today, which I really like, but it seems to do something completely worthless with respect to copying/pasting.  If I highlight some stuff and copy it, when it gets pasted back the newlines are eliminated and there is just a ton of trailing whitespace on each line.

This is really worthless.

All I have in my .emacs right now for CEDET is the following:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.0pre7/common/cedet.el")
(require 'semantic-ia)
(require 'semantic-gcc)
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)
```

Does anybody know how to turn this off?  I can't find anything about this except that the CEDET main page says it has "magic copy & paste".

Comment: That is bizarre. What emacs? cua-mode?

Comment: I suspect you did customized something else beside CEDET, or you are copying from a strange source. I never heard of CEDET messing with copy&paste. Have you tried disable all your other customization except the CEDET stuff (for example, use a completely clean .emacs file with just the CEDET stuff)?

Comment: Also, I would not be so rash to call something "worthless." Just because you can't get something to work (although plenty of others did get CEDET working just fine) does not mean something is worthless. IMHO.

Comment: If I don't call semantic-load-enable-code-helpers, then the problem immediately goes away, which is why I am blaming CEDET.  I even tried commenting out everything in my .emacs except for the CEDET calls above, same problem.

And yes, to be fair, I guess maybe there is some use case for it, but programming with it does suck. 

It's emacs 23.1.1, and I'm not using cua-mode, I am highlighting stuff with the mouse in gnome-terminal.  I thought maybe it was a gnome-terminals fault, but it only does it when copying from emacs.

Comment: OK, ... to clarify ... you're copying and pasting *from a terminal,* which just happens to be running Emacs -- not using Emacs's own cut and paste functionality?